# How to make Specific Java Code in JSP page, run after loading the complete page

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to make JSP page, and run shell scripts on that page. Problem is that the JSP page only loads after executing all the shell scripts. I want the JSP to execute these files on a click of a button. But they are getting executed as soon as the page loads.
Is there a way to make only specific java code work only after a the page is loaded or to execute in an event(like a button click).?

Comment: Not quite, no.  JSP's execute and return HTML to the client browser.  At that point, the Java code is done executing.  However, you can handle an event on a button click using JavaScript and then make another call to your server, where you can execute Java code again.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: So I should have an Event listener in a new Java class?

Comment: Define what you mean by an event listener.  If you do it this way, you'll need a separate HTTP endpoint on the server, that you'll invoke from from the button's onclick event (in HTML).  Remember, there's a difference between when your JSP code executes (on the server while the page is loading) and what happens when a user clicks at button (when it executes in their browser, outside of the scope of your Java code).